# Google Apps Script: How to set script name

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am very new to Google Script and I have created multiple functions for a spreadsheet. Now I am trying to set the name for a script to be shown in the message when the script is executed, same with the message upon script completion:
[Message in Google Sheets when the script runs (In German, saying *Script "" is being executed*)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y4aMk.png).
Is there a function to set this?

I also noticed that the English version of those messages doesn't have quotation marks (e.g. *Running script*), which would imply to me that possibly there is no option to set a name and this is simply a badly translated message.

I tried googling, searching the Google App Script API and searching on Stack Overflow for a function to set the script name, but could not find anything.

Comment: I have also often asked myself whether I can set a name. I also use the German version and wondered about the empty quotation marks "". I have therefore recently sent feedback to Google, let's see if something happens in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you are correct that it is a bad translation. On my spreadsheet, the message says `Running script`, despite my script files and the Project itself having names (I am in English).
I looked through the settings for the script Project and couldn't find anything that could be a place to add a name like that. Googling `can you name a google apps script` also revealed nothing of use. Interestingly, Googling `google apps script bad translation of running script` also comes up with no results, implying that you may be one of the first to bring this up online.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Thanks for supporting my suspicion :) I guess there's no more information on this, therefore I'm gonna accept your answer.

Answer (score 0):

I just started dabbling a little with Google Scripts and encountered the very same "issue" running the German version.

Whenever I start a script in Google Sheets, the message prompt has those empty quotation marks as if there should be a name (of the script) written there, but none was found/given.